# Exporting to CSV in Ruby 1.9.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, export

An existing app, using comma for CSV exports was upgraded to Ruby 1.9.2 And now nothing exports. Basically, the server just sits and spins. I know there is a FasterCSV dependency for comma, but FasterCSV is no longer supported in 1.9.2 as CSV is in the core.

According to the documentation, comma should work even without FasterCSV, but I am not having that experience. I can't get anything to export using this code:

CONTROLLER:

```
format.csv do
    @sis_action_rendered = true
    render :csv => current_user.authorized_clinical_stuff
  end
```

MODEL:

```
comma do # implicitly named :default
user :salutation
name
email
user :login
user :ethnicity
user :gender
user :is_verified => 'APTA Trained'
work_phone
alternate_phone
site_names
site_address
degree
pt_degree
ci_credentialed?
ci_advanced_credentialed?
board_certs
updated_at
end
```

Keep in mind that the model code is pulling info fro several related objects to generate one CSV.

Comment: What happens when you try to generate the CSV in console?

Comment: It would be tough to generate a CSV with the info above.  I can generate the CSV's in some of the examples, but that's just making a CSV of a small hash.  This is more complex.

Answer (score 1):

FasterCSV IS CSV in 1.9.2.

From [the docs](http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/csv/1.9.2/frames):

> This version of the CSV library began its life as FasterCSV. FasterCSV was intended as a replacement to Ruby’s then standard CSV library.
>
> [...]
>
> We must have met our goals because FasterCSV was renamed to CSV and replaced the original library.

Comment: While it's true, comma still doesn't work, so the issue isn't FasterCSV or CSV, it's the gem that depends on them.